# How can I separate a string in Java from full name to last name, first name?

Tags: java, string

How would you take a string that you have input from the keyboard and rearrange it? For example, in my case I am asking the user to import a person's name in "last name, first name" format. I then have to change that to "first name last name".

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void setName() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the last name followed by the first name of" +
            "a student: ");
    name = in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Look into the `split()` method on `String`.

Comment: What is the expected input? For example, am I entering, for John Doe, `Doe John` or `Doe, John`? These will have two different solutions.

Comment: It's going to be incredibly difficult, if not impossible to separate the first and last name of someone if the strings are up against each other.

Comment: I think the expected input is Doe, John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to ask for each name separately, using two calls to Scanner's nextLine() function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstNameLastName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the student's last name: ");
        String lastName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the student's first name: ");
        String firstName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the String.split(" ") which returns a String[].
After that all you have to do is run this array on reverse order printing the strings.

```
String[] tokens = name.split(" "); // split line on string separated by " "
for(int i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

PS: This isn't about java, this is about programming.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating two inputs as below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the last name of a student: ");
        String lastName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the first name of a student: ");
        String firstName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `name.split(delimiter)`. This returns a String array, and each element the array is a component of the String separated by a delimiter that you have to specify as a parameter while using the method.
Eg. From [official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

Regex   Result
:   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

**Approach:** 
`Scanner.nextLine()` returns a String. So that makes the variable `name` a String **instance**. Now you need to find out what methods are supported by String, so that you can invoke it on the instance using a `.`. This is the time to go through the official [Java documentation for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), and find out the methods that you can use. Once you find the methods you want, you can Google for examples :).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpaceReplace {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String firstName;
      String lastName;    

      firstName = scnr.next();
      lastName = scnr.next();
 
  System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
```

}
}